# How do you clear "Frequented" Tags

Tags: support

What does the pale yellow highlighting indicate on certain questions?  It seems to appear at random and changes sometimes, but I haven't been able to find the trigger.

Here are two examples:
[Can I change style properties of several layers simultaneously?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25023/can-i-change-properties-of-several-layers-simultaneously)
[How to randomize colors by class in QGIS new symbology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25017/how-to-randomize-colors-by-class-in-qgis-new-symbology)

This might seem like a surprisingly newbie question, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

---------- Edit

Let me amend my question to ask then how a Frequented tag, as shown below is determined?
[image]

This seems to be causing the highlighting I asked about above, I'm just wondering how to stop it as I don't particularly want those posts highlighted.  There is no place I can find to clear out "Frequented" Tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frequented tags are automatically determined based on the questions you typically ask/answer. It is one of those features that most people either love or hate. I've never been a fan myself, so I use a fake favourite tag to override it:

[image]

In other words, if you set up any favourite or ignored tags, you will stop seeing automatically determined frequented tag highlights.

Comment: Thanks so much Anna, I appreciate it!

Comment: that works like a charm!!..it has been very annoying..

Answer (score 0):

They are tagged with your "favorite" tags.

Look to the upper right (on the *main* site, not here) for a list of your favorited tags.  As an example, I added [support](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) as a favorite just now.  Here's the relevant portion of the screen:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any tags listed as favorite.  Is it then highlighting the ones that I have answered the most questions related to?

Comment: I don't know.  Have you noticed any tags consistently appearing among the yellow questions?

Comment: It seems like the qgis tag is in most of them right now.

Comment: Then you must have added [tag:QGIS] as a favorite tag.

Comment: I updated my question with a screen-shot.  I have not added it as a favorite, but it is listed as "Frequented", which I can find no way of clearing out.

Comment: Thanks.  That clarifies the issue.  I am unable to produce a screen on any SE site that looks like yours, so there's nothing else I can contribute towards a solution.  Let's hope the SE team gets a chance to weigh in on this conversation.